# puppeteer set "isMobile:true" to cause "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning"

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    devtools: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1');
  page.setViewport({
    width: 375,
    height: 667,
    isMobile: true
  });
  await page.goto('https://google.com', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  });

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    console.log(window);
  })
})();
```

When I set isMobile:true in setViewport(),the chromium normally open,but the process reported the following error:

```
(node:13360) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at https://google.com
(node:13360) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed the `await` for the `setUserAgent` method and for the `setViewport` method.

```
(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   devtools: true,
   ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
 });

 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1');
 await page.setViewport({
   width: 375,
   height: 667,
   isMobile: true
 });
 await page.goto('https://google.com', {
   waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
 });

 await page.evaluate(() => {
   console.log(window);
 })
})();
```

Also, you can replace these methods by `emulate` method.

The `emulate` method is a shortcut for calling two methods:

- page.setUserAgent(userAgent)
- page.setViewport(viewport)

Don't forget to import the devices object from the puppeteer. Check out the full list of the [devices](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/DeviceDescriptors.js).

```
const devices = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');

await page.emulate(devices['iPhone 6'])
```

So, your final script should be:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const devices = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');


(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   devtools: true,
   ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
 });

 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.emulate(devices['iPhone 6'])
 await page.goto('https://google.com', {
   waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
 });

 await page.evaluate(() => {
   console.log(window);
 })
})();
```

Comment: awesome! please help me see this [issue_57368020](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57368020/10512637) by the way, if you have time!

Comment: Hi @pigjane. Sure, just answered.

Answer (score 0):

You are using async await, and there is some error originating in your code, and there is no handler for the same, so whenever we use async await, we should surround the code in a try catch block, its a good practice to start a function with try and end it with catch, so whenever a error occurs it goes into the catch block.

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        devtools: true,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1');
        page.setViewport({
        width: 375,
        height: 667,
        isMobile: true
        });
        await page.goto('https://google.com', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
        });

        await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log(window);
        })
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("handle the error here", error)
    }
})();
```