# How to use puppeteer to turn Chromium on in mobile debug mode?

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I want to start Chrome with puppeteer, and in mobile debug mode, **It means to click the 'toggle device toolbar' button in devtools.**

Sorry, I don't have enough prestige to upload pictures.

I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    devtools: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    isMobile:true //I thought it would be fine to set isMobile: true, but not
  });
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 13):

To fully emulate a mobile device, you also have to specify other values like `width`, `height`, `deviceScaleFactor`, `hasTouch` and maybe also the user agent to make the website believe your browser is a mobile device. You can either set them manually (see the answer by Yevhen) or use one of the default device descriptors puppeteer provides via [`puppeteer.devices`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#puppeteerdevices) and apply them by calling [`page.emulate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#pageemulateoptions).

**Code Sample**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 6'];

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto(url);
  // ...
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

The `isMobile` property is a part of the `defaultViewport` object, it means that you should put `isMobile` property inside the `defaultViewport` object.

Like this:

```
defaultViewport: {
  width: 375,
  height: 667,
  isMobile: true,
}
```

Full:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  devtools: true,
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  defaultViewport: {
    width: 375,
    height: 667,
    isMobile: true,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Page.emulate()](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.emulate) method emulates a given device's metrics and user agent. To aid emulation, Puppeteer provides a list of known devices that can be via [KnownDevices](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.knowndevices).

```
import {KnownDevices} from 'puppeteer';
const iPhone = KnownDevices['iPhone 13'];

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  // other actions...
  await browser.close();
})();
```