# Puppeteer Is it possible to click on 'toggle device toolbar' button in devtools

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

Has anybody been able to click the toggle device toolbar' button in dev tools? I am not looking for emulation but to click on that button.

I found the following link, but that is not exactly what I am looking for
[How to use puppeteer to turn Chromium on in mobile debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57368020/how-to-use-puppeteer-to-turn-chromium-on-in-mobile-debug-mode)

Update:: Looks like it is not possible